# Ability to add rel='me' on links on careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks

I'd like to link to my sites from careers and have them linked with the [Google Social Graph api](http://socialgraph-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/findyours.html), for this I'd need to somehow add the rel='me' attribute on links.

Could we have some way to specify on a link if the site is yours in markdown?

Edit: Any official response on this? I think it would be a nice feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the single public cv URL field/link a `rel="nofollow me"` for now -- the same way SO does it.

(note that SO does un-nofollow your profile URL link at 2k rep.)

Answer (score 1):

While you're at it, putting an [hcard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) up somewhere in there would seem like a natural step.

Comment: I believe that Jeff is making the resume page follow hresume format...so an hcard is a logical thing to put there and/or on your SO profile page.